# How to use exception handling in a loop (for n iterations) in python so that results are stored in a file but loop doesn't terminate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to raise exceptions in the form of logs in file and loop should not terminate if exception occurs in a particular iteration.

Input:

```
str = 'my name and age are not known'
for i in range(0,n):
    try:
        list =['name','age']
        for word in list:
           if word in str:
               print('output verified')
           else:
               raise Exception('unmatched values')
               print('unmatched values for iteration n')

     except Exception as ex:
        TestCase.status = FAIL
        raise ex
```

Output:

```
  unmatched values
```

I want output to be stored in a file and loop should continue for next iteration

Comment: You are Raising Exception in except Exception block. That's why it is breaking the loop.

Comment: Even if I comment "raise ex" then the program shows that no exception has occurred and thta test case has passed (although loop doesnt terminate in that case)

Comment: avoid raising an exception from the except block , remove the line `raise ex`

Comment: @csharpcoder oks...but how do I take the logs in a file?

Comment: Look at the native python logger library. You can call logger.ERROR(e). You can direct it's output to a file, and it is good for other types of logging as well. Don't reinvent your own. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html

Comment: Also there is pygogo which wraps the python logger, making it even easier https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the below code logging in the file can be done as per requirement :

```
for i in range(0,n):
    try:
        list =['name','age']
        for word in list:
            if word in str:
                print('output verified')
            else:
                # instead of a generic exception a specific exception can be raised
                raise Exception('unmatched values')
                print('unmatched values for iteration n')
    except Exception:
        TestCase.status = FAIL
        print "Log you result in a file "
        # raise ex  - need not be here
```

Happy Coding :)